# iOS Lag when Updating Button in ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler for Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, uibutton, acaccount

I'm trying to make a toggle button that to indicate sharing to Twitter, like in the Instagram share page that appears after taking a photo.  Specifically it's a UIButton that start in the `Normal` state, then when it's pressed it goes into the `Selected` state with the user's Twitter handle as the title.

On the first tap, it checks with the ACAccountStore for a stored Twitter account.  The problem is lagginess in the ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler in the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` function.  In the handler I make the change to setup the Twitter handle and to select the button.  However, the button takes a long time to visually change the selected state.  This is despite it being in the selected state as verified by an NSLog after the call.

I can't figure out what's causing this lag.  This is the code that handles the button.

```
- (IBAction)pressedTwitter:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    if (button.selected) {
        button.selected = !button.selected;
    } else {
        if (self.twitterAccount != nil) {
            button.selected = !button.selected;
        } else {
            [self getTwitterAccount:button];
        }
    }
}


- (void)getTwitterAccount:(UIButton*)button
{
    // Get Account
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    //  Request permission from the user to access the available Twitter accounts
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

            if ([twitterAccounts count] > 0) {
                self.twitterAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                [self.twitterButton setTitle:self.twitterAccount.username forState:UIControlStateSelected];


                [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:YES];
                self.twitterButton.selected = YES;
                NSLog(@"Twitter Button Selected");

                self.statusLabel.text = @"Twitter Account Found";
            } else {
                [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:NO];
                button.selected = NO;

                NSLog(@"Not enough Twitter Accounts");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Twitter Account Permission Not Granted");

            [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:NO];
            button.selected = NO;

        }
    }];
}

- (void)setTwitterButtonNormalText:(BOOL)accountAvailable
{
    if (accountAvailable) {
        [self.twitterButton setTitle:@"Twitter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.twitterButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.twitterButton setTitle:@"No Twitter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.twitterButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:125./255. green:21./255. blue:0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved a similar problem. It is because the requestAccessToAccountsWithType completion function is on a different thread and you must go back to main thread if you want to intreact with the interface.

You can go back to the main thread:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // code that change the ui, perfom segues, ...
});
```

Try this:

```
- (void)getTwitterAccount:(UIButton*)button
{
    // Get Account
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    //  Request permission from the user to access the available Twitter accounts
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

            if ([twitterAccounts count] > 0) {
                self.twitterAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                // go back to the main thread
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.twitterButton setTitle:self.twitterAccount.username forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:YES];
                    self.twitterButton.selected = YES;
                });
                NSLog(@"Twitter Button Selected");

                self.statusLabel.text = @"Twitter Account Found";
            } else {
                // go back to the main thread
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:NO];
                    button.selected = NO;
                });
                NSLog(@"Not enough Twitter Accounts");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Twitter Account Permission Not Granted");
            // go back to the main thread
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self setTwitterButtonNormalText:NO];
                button.selected = NO;
            });
        }
    }];
}
```